# Executing a script that uses a library not installed in another pc, will install it?

Tags: python, scripting

This might sound like a stupid question, but I got thinking about it by doing some security project:
Doing a script for whatever reason and using libraries in it sounds just fine to me as you will install those libraries because it will execute in your pc.

But what if the script is, for example, to attack (execute the script) in someone's computer? That person might not have a specific library installed (for example `pywhois` for python and get the `whois` information). So the script would not work? Or in the same script, can you use a command to install the library without the user noticing?

Comment: In theory, sure.

Comment: But what about the "executing in another pc" part that I mentioned? What if the other user has no libraries installed?@Torxed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A malicious script running on a different machine which does not have its requirements can still execute, it just has to run ensure-pip and then pip as a subprocess, it will be able to obtain the necessary libraries just fine as long as it only needs them in the user site-packages and not the system.

Python can lazy import so the first step would be to test, then catch an import error, and run `pip -r requirements.txt`, then import again or just run pip every time.

Comment: And will the user have any kind of knowledge (or is the user able to know) about a library being installed, when and due to what (in this case, a script has run the ensue-pip)?

Comment: Nope, as long as a program doesn't need privileges, then as long as you at some point gave it permission to run, it's allowed to do whatever it likes (baring additional sandbox policy), and is under no obligation to provide you output.  You might still be able to detect it executing, depending on how you gave it permission to run, for example if you gave it permission to run in a terminal emulator.